How to calculate a rolling sum for a group of data
I have a set of historical data, let's say from the year 2000 stored in table A. The data structure of the table simply composes of 2 column, the date dt and item
dt,   item
1/20/2000, A1
1/20/2000, A2
1/20/2000, A3
....
6/1/2024, A1
---

How do I calculate the historic count of each item for the last 2 years?
In other word, I would like to see the results like this:
202406, A1, Count of A1 until 6/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
202406, A2, Count of A2 until 6/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
202406, A3, Count of A3 until 6/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
202405, A1, Count of A1 until 5/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
202405, A2, Count of A2 until 5/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
202405, A3, Count of A3 until 5/1/2024 since 1/1/2000
...
202206, A1, Count of A1 until 6/1/2022 since 1/1/2000
202206, A2, Count of A2 until 6/1/2022 since 1/1/2000
202206, A3, Count of A3 until 6/1/2022 since 1/1/2000

I can easily group and count the item in a specific month using this:
select  202406,  item, count(item)
from table A
where datetime < 6/1/2024
group by left(convert(varchar,dt,112),6), item

I can also list the 24 past months since today
select dt2=format(dateadd(month,2-n,getdate()),'yyyyMM')
from
(
  select top (24) n=row_number() over (order by (select null))
  from sys.object)
)

But I can not combine my 2 SQL statements above to get the result I want.
Basically, I just would like to get something like this
select x, item, count(item) from tablea where month(dt) <x group by x, item

with x running from currentmonth-24 to currentmonth.
Can it be easily achieved with 1 simple SQL statement instead of using stored procedure?

count() over (partition by item order by dt rows between 23 preceding and current row) You'll want to change your query to group by dt, item This does assume there no month gaps in the data. SQL Server doesn't support using range between yet unfortunately.

You could also do a cross apply or scalar query: from tablea a cross apply (select count(*) from tablea a2 where a2.item = a.item and a2.dt >= dateadd(month, -24, a.dt) and a2.dt < a.dt) as month24(itemcount) Adjust the endpoints accordingly. I'm not quite sure which 24 months you need. This approach will work with gaps though.

Are you using SQL Server? I suggest that you add a sql-server tag to better reach your intended audience. Also post your version information (select @@version). Some newer functions like GENERATE_SERIES() and DATETRUNC() might be preferred when generating your date list. A solution may be something like select D.MonthEnd, H.Item, count(*) as ItemCount from HistoryTable H join (date-generator-logic) D ON H.dt <= D.MonthEnd group by D.MonthEnd, H.Item order by D.MonthEnd, H.Item. Usually it is best to perform date logic using date types and only apply formatting to the end result.

@TN: Yes, I am using SQL server 2018

@shawnt00: Thanks for the hint.. but could you please elaborate a bit more? I am not really sure how to tie the month in the select item from tablea where the month of the item in tablea is less than the month x, x running from previous 24 months until current month

@user1205746 - There is no such thing as SQL server 2018. What does the select @@version command tell you.

@TN: Oops.. sorry.. It should read 2019.. Microsoft SQL Server 2019(RTM-CU26)

Basically, I just would like to get this "select x, item, count(item) from tablea where month(dt) <x group by x, item with x running from currentmonth-24 to currentmonth. Can it be achieved in 1 simple statement instead of using stored procedure?

Another couple of questions: (1) Do your date ranges end at the first of the month ("202406" includes dates through 2024-06-01) or the end of the month ("202406" includes dates through 2024-06-30)? (2) For the "Count of A1 until 6/1/2024 since 1/1/2000" values in your expected results, are you just looking for the integer count?

FYI... you talk about your alternative as adding a stored procedure, but a stored procedure doesn't give you any different options than you have here... it just encapsulates some statements.

You can accomplish what you want by:

Encapsulating a modified version of your date generator in a subselect or a CTE.
Join the generated dates with your data using a date inequality condition.
Group by date and item while calculating and a count.
Format the results as desired.

with Months as (
    select eomonth(getdate(), 1 - N.n) as endDate
    from (
        select top (24) row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
        from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) N1(n) -- up to 10
        cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) N2(n) -- up to 100
    ) N
)
select
    M.endDate,
    convert(char(6), M.endDate, 112) as endMonth, -- yyyymmdd truncated
    A.item,
    count(*) as itemCount
from TableA A
join Months M
    on A.dt <= M.endDate
group by M.endDate, A.item
order by M.endDate, A.item;

The date generator uses a VALUES source instead of sys.objects, because the latter did not have enough rows in the fiddle environment. It also calculates a true end-of-month end date instead of a "YYYYMM" format. I also adjusted the range down by one month, so that it ends with the current month.
Results



endDate
endMonth
item
itemCount




2022-07-31
202207
A1
1


2022-07-31
202207
A2
1


2022-07-31
202207
A3
1


...
...
...
...


2024-06-30
202406
A1
2


2024-06-30
202406
A2
1


2024-06-30
202406
A3
1



See this db<>fiddle for a demo

Thank you for the very elegant solution! This is the piece that I did not know how to link properly! The solution is concise and easy to understand. Thanks again!

Perhaps the following example will help you.
WITH months (n, ldom) AS (
  SELECT -23 AS n, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -23) AS ldom 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), n + 1) 
  FROM months 
  WHERE n < 0
)
SELECT
  ldom,
  agg.item,
  agg.cnt
FROM months
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT items.item, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM items
  WHERE items.dt <= months.ldom
  GROUP BY items.item
) agg

Here the CTE months gets the last dates of 24 months from the current date. This can be obtained in different ways. For example, in SQl Server 2022 via GENERATE_SERIES.
db<>fiddle

Thanks! That would probably work also. I wish I could mark both as answer. There are always more solutions to a question but unfortunately, only one solution could be marked as answer.
